# DNS name different from the actual name of the computer-searching returning error

Tags: 2007

scenario

DNS -- http:\jondoe

actual name of server --jane

I have set up windows sharepoint search services and they work fine when users use http://jane

but when users try to search using dns name ( http://jondoe) , it gives an error

environment is MOSS 2007 - windows 2008 , sql server 2008

central administration >> Operations >> services on server shows --jane ..
so how do i fix it so that users can perfrom search using the dns name (jondoe)rather than using the actual name (jane)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the DNS entry for jondoe points to your Sharepoint server.

Second, set up an alternate access mapping (AAM) entry in Central Administration for jondoe.  Google AAM or 'Alternate Access Mapping' for more info.  This essentially allows you to have more than one DNS name point to the same web application / content database, so that you could have both http://companysite.internal and http://www.companysite.com point to the same web application.